# Close app while in background at certain times

Tags: ios, background, reset

What I want to do is to tell the user to press the home button and reopen the app, which requires the app quitting upon entering the background - it's for a reset app settings thing. But I do want the app to background in all other times. Do I use the app delegate?

If there is an easier way, e.g. somehow restarting the main view controller then that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
    For your app to run in background always use this code.
    Put this code under the method ApplicationDidEnterBackground  in your app delegate class            .m file
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
     UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
        UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;
        bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
            [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        }];

}
```

Comment: Thannks but I want to not multitask at certain times.It seems to multitask without any code

Comment: the above code is to run your app on background .Can you be a bit more clearer on what you need ?